# html tag inside advanced php

Tags: php, html

I am unable to find what is the problem. `HTML` tags are inside the `PHP`, but not working as expected:

```
<td>{{$trade->is_action==1 ? 'Bought' : '<?php echo "<span class='badge-pill' style='background-color:#f44336' >" ?> Sold <?php echo "</span>" ?>' }}</td>
```

From the image, you can clearly check it.

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: There's no issue with the above code. Only issue is that the editor is confused about the usage of single quotes here. It's perfectly fine and normal.

Comment: Since your output looks that way, I feel that your `{{}}` templating engine is not working. Are you using something like blade?

Comment: i dont what is right way to do this but, i also posted result. @PraveenKumar There is issued but i dont know where.

Comment: Check my other comment too... `:)` Let me know.

Comment: Yes I am using `laravel .blade`.@PraveenKumar

Comment: You don't need to use `<?php` tags there!

Comment: oh yeah... you are right. I can use direct `@`. isn't it?

Comment: Yep. That's right. Also the answer by u_mulder is a good solution... `:)`

Comment: let me try with `@`. thank you so much. I already thump up to u_mulder

Comment: Great... :) Sent you a message in FB too... :)

Comment: Ok @PraveenKumar but till i am unable to solve this problem, because i dont know how to `@`

Comment: Gave you a better solution... `:)`

Comment: Oh! Its ok @PraveenKumar

Comment: u have php tags inside of {{  no good

Comment: that's is solved @Andrew. Now I am in another problem of relationship in laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the above solution of u_mulder, I would like to add to it. If you want to display HTML in blade, use `{!! !!}`:

```
<td>{!! $trade->is_action==1 ? 'Bought' : '<span class="badge-pill" style="background-color:#f44336"> Sold </span>' !!}</td>
```

To explain further, you don't need to use PHP inside the blade syntax.

Comment: Can you help me how to use via `@`?

Comment: I did not try because, i dont know how to use @ but, if you give me example with my `code`. i can learn

Comment: `@{{ }}` is for outputting raw HTML. And what you need for the time being is what I have in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Blade `{{ }}` means that you output data already, there's no need to use `<?php` and `echo`, Blade does that for you, just provide a string that you want to output:

```
<td>{!! $trade->is_action==1 ? 'Bought' : '<span class="badge-pill" style="background-color:#f44336"> Sold </span>' !!}</td>
```

**Update**: to output raw html - use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`.

Comment: That's a nice one. You beat me before I answer. To be frank, I had almost the same answer written... `:D`

Comment: Your code given me result as `<span class="badge-pill" style="background-color:#f44336"> Sold </span>`

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati Try using single `{!! !!}`?

Comment: No, it's more complicated here. Blade `{{}}` escapes html by default. Raw html outputed with `{!! !!}`

Comment: Ok @PraveenKumar

Comment: hello @PraveenKumar I again stacked in another question. Can you help?

Comment: @PraveenKumar here is link for that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907380/get-images-via-relationship/50907729?noredirect=1#comment88815664_50907729