# Get Images via relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

From the `charts`, I want to get each images which `trade_id` via relationship.

For example, if `trade_id` is 62, from the `charts` table, get all images which has 62 in `trade_id`.

`charts` table structure:

[image]

**`Trade` model:**

```
    public function chart()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chart');
}
```

```html
@if($trades)
     <tbody>
     @foreach($trades as $trade)
           <tr>
              <td> <img src="{{$trade->chart->file }}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%"> </td>
          </tr>
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
            @else
            <h1>No trades</h1>
@endif
```

OUTPUT has error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$file (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $trades = Trade::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
    return view('member.add-single-trade.index', compact('trades'));

}
```

DD($Trade): Result

```css
Trade {#541 ▼
  #dates: array:1 [▼
    0 => "deleted_at"
  ]
  #fillable: array:10 [▼
    0 => "user_id"
    1 => "symbol_id"
    2 => "is_action"
    3 => "rate"
    4 => "tradedate"
    5 => "note"
    6 => "trade_id"
    7 => "exchange_id"
    8 => "market_id"
    9 => "stoploss"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1
    "symbol_id" => 5
    "exchange_id" => 1
    "market_id" => 1
    "is_action" => 1
    "rate" => 5641
    "tradedate" => "2018-04-05 00:00:00"
    "note" => ""
    "created_at" => "2018-04-18 13:00:23"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-18 13:00:23"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "quantities" => 0
    "stoploss" => 0
  ]
  #original: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1
    "symbol_id" => 5
    "exchange_id" => 1
    "market_id" => 1
    "is_action" => 1
    "rate" => 5641
    "tradedate" => "2018-04-05 00:00:00"
    "note" => ""
    "created_at" => "2018-04-18 13:00:23"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-18 13:00:23"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "quantities" => 0
    "stoploss" => 0
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

Comment: First `dd();` your query and check is it give you file data?? Also, you make hasMany relation in trade model, what about chart model?? I think there is belongsTo relation.

Comment: This blade and table, can i use `DD();`?@HirenGohel

Comment: I have also one question, should i keep relationship into `chart` table?

Comment: For now, try this: `src="{{$trade->chart->file }}"`

Comment: i already use that, @HirenGohel

Comment: both are same, there 's no difference. @HirenGohel

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati The difference is that after `chart` in your code you have `()`, try removing them so it's just `chart->`.

Comment: @Jonathon: I told her, but she told me not working! And she also understood the same. with `()` and without `()`

Comment: ohh yeaah... i am sorry.....(). @HirenGohel

Comment: error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$file (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati: No problem. Now it's works after removing?

Comment: actually not worked... error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over the charts :

```
@if($trades)
     <tbody>
     @foreach($trades as $trade)
        @foreach($trade->chart as $chart)
           <tr>
              <td> <img src="{{$chart->file }}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%"> </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
            @else
            <h1>No trades</h1>
@endif
```

And one more thing the path of the image will not work, assuming you have the images in images folder inside the public one, you have to chage :

```
<img src="{{$chart->file}}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%">
```

To

```
<img src="{{Storage::get('public/charts/', $chart->file) }}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%">
```

Comment: I think you are perfect. let me try.

Comment: I will check in 5min. @Maraboc

Comment: error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$chart (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)`

Comment: This is code of my relationship: `public function chart()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chart');
    }`

Comment: I have `charts` folder into `public path`.

Comment: I think issue is in relationship, which relation should i use here? and which mode i should use relationship?

Comment: till error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)` @Maraboc

Comment: error is changed as :`Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)` after added `$trade` instead of `$trades`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173345/discussion-between-maraboc-and-kinnari-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public function charts() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Chart');
}
```

view:

```
 @foreach($trades as $trade)
       <tr>
          <td>@foreach($trade->charts->all() as $chart) <img src="{{$chart->file }}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%">@endforeach</td>
      </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: images **might more than 1**, and which mode should i use `relationship code`?

Comment: answer is edited in case each trade has many charts. please check again

Comment: error : `syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)`

Comment: again error : `Call to a member function all() on null`

Comment: Hello, Can You guide me?

Comment: `$trade->charts` is null. there is something error with table or relations.

Comment: actually, there is images but i am getting error : `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\try\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\index.blade.php)` @Metalik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173343/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-metalik).

Comment: I have added `Controller `in question @Matealik

Comment: after view foreach add `{{dd($trade)}}` then send result

Comment: I have posted result of `{{dd($trade)}}` @Metalik

Comment: there is no relation. try this `$trades = Trade::with('charts')->where('user_id', $user_id )->get();`

Comment: can you guide me what to do? actually my brain is not working now. @Metalik I have spent 7hours behind it

Comment: error again : `Call to undefined relationship [charts] on model [App\Trade].`

Comment: trade model has charts method?

Comment: This code has `Trade Model` :  `public function chart()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Chart');
    }
`

Comment: now found result in DD: ` #relations: array:1 [▼
    "charts" => Collection {#538 ▶}`

Answer (score 0):

add relationships into foreach.

```
 @foreach($trades->chart as $trade)
           <tr>
              <td> <img src="{{$trade->file }}"> </td>
          </tr>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: this is nothing to result

Comment: Hello,@Ali Ozen, do you know what should i do?